# Pass selected values to html.actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 dropdowns for month (which store values 1 - 12) and for year:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Month",ViewData["MonthList"] as SelectList)
@Html.DropDownList("Year", ViewData["YearList"] as SelectList)
```

And I have an HTML.ActionLink that forwards to controller action which requires Date as input:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show for This Month", "EntriesInMonth", "Entries"
    , new { date = DateTime.Now }, null)
```

The question is how can I make a date object from selected values and pass it to the ActionLink when I clicking on it?

Comment: This is probably going to be easier by using a form submit than a link.  But if you must use a link then you're going to need to modify it with JavaScript to get the values from the `select` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a form for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EntriesInMonth", "Entries"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Month",ViewData["MonthList"] as SelectList)
    @Html.DropDownList("Year", ViewData["YearList"] as SelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="Show for This Month">
}
```

Comment: Since OP is currently making a GET, this should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("EntriesInMonth", "Entries", FormMethod.Get))`